# Strange behavior editing photos in photoshop and back in lightroom

Tags: lightroom, photoshop, error, import

When I want to edit in Photoshop a photo I search it in my Lightroom Library and then I make right click -> Edit in -> Photoshop

I edit the photo in Photoshop and then I save it with Command+S.

The new image is saved in .tif format in the right folder next to the not edited one.

But when I try to find it in Lightroom it is not visible in the right folder.

The strange thing is that Lightroom seems to import it to a new empty folder new to the highest folder (see image).

[image]

This is rather annoying and I know this is not normal because I used to make this before and the result was not the same.
I use Adobe Lightroom Classic CC 8.2 and Adobe Photoshop CC 2019 20.0.4

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution by my by myself! I had changed pc during the moving I have changed the user name from Fabio to fabio. Lightroom had found the files but does not recognize the folders as the same.